# mysql #1064 error. Insert into

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, insert-into

this is something that clearly i can't see, but i bet it's a super easy thing that i can't find. here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO match (g1_id,g1_pv,g1_pe,g1_pb,g2_id,g2_pv,g2_pe,g2_pb,g3_id,g3_pv,g3_pe,g3_pb,g4_id,g4_pv,g4_pe,g4_pb,g5_id,g5_pv,g5_pe,g5_pb,gv_id_spareggio) VALUES (2,12,15,3,1,32,32,2,4,43,43,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

this is the error i get:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match (g1_id,g1_pv,g1_pe,g1_pb,g2_id,g2_pv,g2_pe,g2_pb,g3_id,g3_pv,g3_pe,g3_pb,g' at line 1
```

What's next that "g" that bother him?

Thanks.

Comment: `match` is your table name? if yes, use backquotes onto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think match  is a reserved keyword in mysql. So you should use `match` or "match" if ANSI SQL Mode is enabled

Answer (score 0):

match is a keyword in `mysql` use quotes:

```
INSERT INTO 'match' ...
```